# ML. How to typecast?

Tags: types, casting, type-conversion, ml

If i have the following datatype declared:

datatype 'a data = None | Single of 'a | Multiple of 'a list;

and I need to create a function witch receives Multiple and if it contains only one object then it will return that object but as Single otherwise it just returns Multiple. Is it possible?

Comment: What you are asking is possible and it has nothing to do with type conversion (and even less with type-casting, which is a syntactic construct to indicate type conversion in languages that allow it—ML does not). Constructors (such as `Single` and `Multiple`) are not types.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how one might do that?

Comment: Yes: with pattern-matching. I can't provide the function as I can only read Standard ML, not write it.